# How am I able to check emails on outlook in my office windows machine without entering password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, authentication, windows-domain, kerberos

I have a basic question. At work, I log on to a domain from my work machine using a password. Then, once I am logged-in, I can read mails in outlook without having to enter any password. What I understand:

-- Outlook connects to exchange server (which stores my emails or gathers emails from where 
they are stored) and gets my emails

-- How is the above authentication done? Since it doesn't again ask me for password, it must use the windows logon authentication here too. One way I know to achieve single sign-on is kerberization. **Is kerberization what is coming into picture here or something else** and my understanding is missing something?

Thanks,

Addition:
Does NTLM something come into picture here somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exchange is using the same kind of authentication/authorisation as, for example, file shares.

When you connect with an appropriately configured transport (Named Pipes are the simplest) then your authentication information is carried across. In a domain (required for Exchange) this uses Active Directory's Kerberos derived system that means you password (or a hash of your password) is not sent, but rather a token that AD gives you computer. The Exchange server then checks that token with an AD to verify you identity.

See [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) for more information.

(NTLM also provides SSO in a similar way, but it has some security problems and has been replaced by Kerberos in most places.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't enter your password initially when first setting up Outlook? I believe that as standard it just remembers this.

You can (if wanted) get it to ask your password every time via tools > email accounts > add or modify an existing account > change > more settings > security > "always prompt for username and password"

Answer (score 0):

The system is what's known as Single Sign On (Wikipedia artice [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)).

Exchange is the back end system for outlook in most enterprise environments and it integrates very tightly with the active directory in Windows Server.